# Monodroid: Document element did not appear

Tags: c#, android, xml-serialization, xamarin.android

I'm trying to deserialize an XML file to an object in my android application, developed with Xamarin Monodroid).

I generate my XML in pure C#, copy the XML file in the assets folder of the application, then deserialize it when the app starts.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyGreatObject
{
    public string ObjectName;
    public string ObjectLink;
    public string ObjectStuff;
    public List<OtherGreatObject> OtherObjects;

    public MyGreatObject()
    {
        OtherObjects = new List<OtherGreatObject>();
    }
}
```

The `OtherGreaterObject` has common attributes (string format I mean).
So, I generate the XML and have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyGreatObject xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ObjectName>This is the object name</ObjectName>
  <ObjectLink>http://www.xamarin-is-awesome.com</ObjectLink>
  <ObjectStuff>Description</ObjectStuff>
  <OtherObjects>
        <OtherGreatObject>...</OtherGreatObject>
        <OtherGreatObject>...</OtherGreatObject>
  </OtherObjects>
</MyGreatObject>
```

And I try to deserialize it like that:

```
internal static class SerializableXml
{
    public static MyGreatObject LoadData(Context context_, string fileName_)
    {
        MyGreatObject greatObject = new MyGreatObject();
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyGreatObject));
            using (Stream input = context_.Assets.Open(fileName_, Android.Content.Res.Access.Buffer))
                greatObject = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(input) as MyGreatObject;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Error("XML", "ERROR IN LOADING");
            Android.Util.Log.Error("XML", exception.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        return greatObject;
    }
}
```

But I get the error `System.Xml.XmlException: Document element did not appear.  Line 1, position 1.`.

```
at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read() [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read() [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToCOntent() [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadRoot() [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(System.Xml.SerializationReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I lost plenty of time on Google, so I'm asking you.

Thanks a lot in advance for the help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problem resolved.

Google didn't find anything about the error (in my situation).
I thought that the `XmlSerializer` (I read about an error in Mono Framework few years ago), but it wasn't.

Than, I thought that something was wrong in the XML, but wasn't sure at all. Why would I have such a error message ? I should have "Invalid node name", "Invalid attribute", or something like that.

But I was right. **A node had a bad name**, and this returns `Document element did not appear. Line 1, position 1.` *(or the exception message that means nothing at all)* !

So, problem solved.

Comment: What was the "bad name of the node"? I'm facing the same error here, but the thing is that the XmlSerializer wrote it, so I don't understand why the XmlDeserializer cannot read it. It's not like I'm trying to read a Xml that I've created manually... I even passed my XML to W3C Xml Validator : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp and it tells me everything is fine.

Comment: Your XML can be understandable as an XML but cannot be deserialized into your object because of your object specification. I mean List, object[], primary types, and so on. You should post some of your code, it would be easier to help.

Comment: I'm thinking about it, but I would have to create a question for it, I cannot post here. I will see if I can fix the problem, otherwise I might post a question and I will write the link here so you could reply if you know the answer. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error as well using Xamarin.iOS 8.4
Even though on Android everything worked fine, on the iOS build I received the error:

```
Document element did not appear.  Line 1, position 1.
```

my XML file (which was not written manually, but serialized in c#) had the following line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

**I fixed it by adding the encoding property** as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

If you have many files, clearly this is not the best solution, but perhaps there is a method in the serializer that edits the encoding. I did not look into that since I did not need to, but if anyone comes across this issue, it may be a start.